# ASP.NET MVC simplify routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

How can I simplify these routes?

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetUsersRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/User",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "GetUsers" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetUserRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/User/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "GetUser", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetEmailAddressRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/User/GetEmailAddress/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "User", action="GetEmailAddress", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);


/*** Default ***/
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I needed to add the GetEmailAddressRoute because the controller didn't know which action to take for a path like `api/User/5`. However, since then former routes like `api/User` don't lead to the correct action.

Some action signatures from the controller:

```
public Object GetUsers() { };

public Object GetUser(int id) { };

public HttpResponseMessage GetEmailAddress (int id) { };
```

But now I'd need to add another route for the Post actions. Is there a simpler way?

**Update**: What helped me for posting new users was to remove the action from the first route. Now it is

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetUsersRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/User",
    defaults: new { controller = "User" }
);
```

Comment: I don't think that you need another route for post actions. I've never seen that done before, unless you are posting elsewhere. Try changing your default `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the new routing attribute feature coming with web api 2 :

```
[Route("api/User")]
public Object GetUsers() { };

[Route("api/User/{id}")]
public Object GetUser(int id) { };

[Route("api/User/GetEmailAddress/{id}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetEmailAddress (int id) { };
```

Comment: you could use `RoutePrefix` to avoid repeating 'api/User'